# Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Tags: matlab

Hello guys i am writing a matlab code, when i write this program it prints to me a mistake message for "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts" can anyone help me?

```
%% INITIALIZATION

% Size of matrix A [rows, cols]
[ma, na] = size(A);

% Size of matrix B [rows, cols]
[mb, nb] = size(B);

% Create matrix C all zeros
C = zeros(ma+mb-1, na+nb-1);
[mc, nc] = size(C);


% Create matrix T.
T = [mb-1, nb-1];


% Add mb-1 rows of zeros up and down matrix A
% Add nb-1 cols of zeros left and right matrix A
padA = padarray(A, [mb-1 nb-1]);


% flip matrix B on both directions
flipB = flip(flip(B, 1), 2);

%% CONVOLUTION

for i = 1 : mb
    for j = 1 : nb
        for x = 1 : mc
           for z = 1 : nc

                  T(i+x-1,j+z-1) = flipB(i,j) * padA;
                  C(x,z) = C(x,z) + T(i+x-1,j+z-1);

            end
        end
    end  
end


end
```

Comment: In which line?!?!

Comment: in T(i+x-1,j+z-1) = flipB(i,j) * padA;

Comment: What is `size(flipB(i,j)*padA`?

Comment: flipB = [3,3] and padA is padArray of A which is 256x256

Comment: No, not the size of each, the size of the result.

Comment: You're trying to assign an array (`flipB(i,j) * padA`) to a single scalar (`T(i+x-1,j+z-1)`). That will never work. Also, `T` is not a matrix of all zeros, despite what your comment says.

Comment: Sorry for the comment i forgot to change it. how should i write this command in order to work?

Comment: the size of the result should be the same with padA

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the line:

```
T(i+x-1,j+z-1) = flipB(i,j) * padA;
```

Essentially, `T(i+x-1,j+z-1)` and `flipB(i,j) * padA` are not the same size. You can debug this by inserting `size` functions to print the size during the loop iteration. Ex:

```
size(T(i+x-1,j+z-1))
size(flipB(i,j) * padA)
```

The error will go away once the `rhs` and `lhs` side of the equal sign are the same size.